# Update a collections view dynamically after removing the models from it

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following code:

```
// Create the Backbone view to display a list of vehicles

var Vehicle = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: "registrationNumber",
  urlRoot: "/api/vehicles",
  validate: function(attrs) {
    if (!attrs.registrationNumber)
        return "Registration number is required!";
  }
});

var Vehicles = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Vehicle
});

// View for the model
var VehicleView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagname: "li",
  attributes: {
    "data-color" : "Rainbow"
  },
  events: {
    "click .deleteButton" : "deleteVehicle"
  },

  render: function() {
    var template = _.template($("#vehicleTemplate").html());
    var html = template(this.model.toJSON()); 
    this.$el.html(html);
    return this;
  },

  deleteVehicle: function() {
    console.log("Model destroyed");
    this.model.destroy();
  }
});

var VehiclesView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName : "ul",

  initialize: function () {
    this.model.on("change", this.render, this);
    this.model.on("add", this.render, this);
    this.model.on("remove", this.render, this);
  },

render: function() {
    var self = this;

    this.model.each(function(vehicle){ 
        var vehicleView = new VehicleView({model: vehicle}); 
        self.$el.append(vehicleView.render().$el); 
    });
}

});

// Add cars to the collection
var car1 = new Vehicle({registrationNumber: "XLI887", color: "blue"});
var car2 = new Vehicle({registrationNumber: "ZNP123", color: "blue"});
var car3 = new Vehicle({registrationNumber: "XUV456", color: "grey"});

var vehicles = new Vehicles([car1, car2, car3]);

var vehiclesView = new VehiclesView({el: "#container", model: vehicles});
vehiclesView.render();
```

The rendering looks good, but when I click delete, the new collection (with one less element) is appended to the existing view of the older collection. How do I replace the old collection view with the new one?

Answer (score 0):

I modified the "remove" handler as below and it dynamically removed the "li" element from the list and showed the new collection.

```
initialize: function () {
    this.model.on("change", this.render, this);
    this.model.on("add", this.render, this);
    this.model.on("remove", this.onDelete, this);
},

onDelete : function(vehicle) {
    console.log("Vehicle deleted");
    this.$el.find("li#" + vehicle.id).remove();
}
```